# How to Deserialize Json Array to list (or) Array

Tags: arrays, json, c#-4.0, json.net, asp.net-ajax

I am getting the data from an Ajax call its giving json output has mentioned below
In my Code-behind **Jobsheet** parameters has the **json Array object** how to passes that parameter in the deserialization and get the values from it

This is my Json output:

```
string Jobsheet =[{"var_name_data":"Demo1Demo2Demo3Demo4Demo5Demo6Demo7Demo8Demo9Demo10 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10"}]
```

My  Class:

```
 public class RootObject
{
    public List<User> var_name_data { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public int customer_id { get; set; }
}
```

In my Code-behind:

```
   [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static object Details4(string selectedJobSheet)
    {

        try
        {
            var des = (RootObject)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(selectedJobSheet, typeof(RootObject));

            return des.var_name_data.Count.ToString();


        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }

    }
```

Its throwing an Exception:

> An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in EBCheckList.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'EBCheckDAL.RootObject' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
>   Path '', line 1, position 1. occurred

Please help me to Convert the above json data to list (or) Array of elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deserialize the `Jobsheet` to list of object not to the `RootObject`, like the following code:
1 - Create object that match to the json object:

```
public class User
{
    public string Var_name_data { get; set; }
}
```

2 - Deserialize the `Jobsheet`:

```
string Jobsheet = @"[{""var_name_data"":""Demo1Demo2Demo3Demo4Demo5Demo6Demo7Demo8Demo9Demo10 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10""}]";

List<User> users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(Jobsheet);
```

**Demo**:

```
foreach(User user in users)
{
    Console.WriteLine(user.Var_name_data);
}
// or
Console.WriteLine(users.count);
```

**Result**:

```
Demo1Demo2Demo3Demo4Demo5Demo6Demo7Demo8Demo9Demo10 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
//or
1
```

I hope this will helps you.